# Identifying integers in a file using getchar

Tags: c

I'm reading a text file using getchar() and I'm need to print all the integers in a file. If the file looks like:

```
hello 42 world
```

I know how to find single digit integers because getchar() gives me the ascii value of each character in the file so I need to look for values between 48 and 57 (ascii values for 0-9) but I can't figure out how to do this for n digits. In the example above I would find the values 52 and 50 for "42" but how can I turn that into 42?

I thought about creating a char array and when I find a digit put it in the array and then use atoi() to convert the string to an int but it feels like a bad solution, if it would even work.

Comment: Don't read the file character-by-character.  Rather fetch an entire line at a time using `getline`.  Then, scan that line for a digit, if you find one, use `strtol` to parse it and continue scanning from the position after the number (`strtol` will tell you where this is).

Comment: The standard way to calculate the value of an integer read one char at a time is `int val = 0, ch; while (isdigit(ch = getchar())) val = 10 * val + (ch - '0');`.

Comment: Oh, and if you consider `-42` a value different from `42`, you'll need to be more careful.  If so, also think about how you want to deal with `- 42`.

Comment: i suggest you to think in a systematical way. what will you do without language restriction? i would choose regex:　`m/-?\d+/g`. this is the point. construct the automaton to simulate this regular expression and in this way, your code should be much cleaner and neater.

Comment: Note that the `isdigit()` function from `<ctype.h>` is better than relying on codes 48-57.  There are codesets (albeit arcane ones such as EBCDIC) where the values for the digits are 240-249, for instance.  Do you have to worry about overflow?  Will any of the numbers have more than 16 digits in them?  Do you have to worry about Unicode encodings?

Answer (score 0):

Gene's approach packed in a program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

main()
{
    int ch;
    do
    {
        int val = 0, digits = 0;
        while (isdigit(ch = getchar())) ++digits, val = 10 * val + (ch - '0');
        if (digits) printf("%d\n", val);
    } while (ch != EOF);
    return 0;
}
```